# Generating list or paths of stylesheets and javascript files in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm writing a Rails4 app that uses a custom cache manifest file which needs to include references to all the required Javascript and CSS files. Due to the nature of the application, the Rack Offline gem can't be used.

The `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag` calls produce the correct list of files (as generated by the asset pipeline) but embed them in HTML tags.

Is there a way to get the paths to all the compiled javascript and stylesheet files in the controller?

eg.

```
/assets/custom.css?body=1
/assets/incidents.css?body=1
/assets/users.css?body=1
/assets/application.css?body=
/assets/jquery.js?body=1
/assets/bootstrap/affix.js?body=1
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That one was fun! Had to go into the Sprockets source to figure it out.

```
asset_list = Rails.application.assets.each_logical_path(*Rails.application.config.assets).to_a
```

You can then go in a grep through the asset list, something like:

```
asset_list.grep(/\.(js|css)/)
```

EDIT:

If you want the hex digests, you could do something like:

```
environment = Rails.application.assets
asset_list = environment.each_logical_path(*Rails.application.config.assets).to_a
asset_list.map! { |asset| environment.find_asset(asset).digest_path rescue nil }.compact
```

Comment: Unfortunately the list it comes up with doesn'

Comment: It's close, but unfortunately the list it comes up with doesn't take into account all the asset pipeline stuff. e.g. It includes application.js, but in development mode not the list of files required by application.js - nor the mangling of their names (appending ?body=1 in development, usinhg checksums in production)

Comment: It now includes the hex digests

Comment: Thanks. Glad somebody can understand the sprockets-rails code!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @kdeisz research, this code worked in the controller for the manifest file:

```
@assets = Rails.application.assets.each_logical_path(*Rails.application.config.assets).to_a
@assets = @assets.map{ |p| view_context.compute_asset_path(p) }
render 'manifest.text', content_type: 'text/cache-manifest'
```

The `compute_asset_path` function is needed to get the actual asset path.

Note: I haven't yet tested this in production mode. It works in development mode if you set `config.assets.debug = false`